# Mobile code programming

Tags: java, javascript, networking, network-programming

My boss has asked me to implement a project that includes writing a "mobile code" using java programing language. This code will be transferred on the network of nodes ,going from the source code node to other nodes,  and at a point returning to it with certain information.

Since its the first time somebody asks me to implement a networking project ..i have no idea what "mobile codes " are.

So i tried to do a lil research and it turned out that "mobile code is software transferred between systems, e.g. transferred across a network or via a USB flash drive, and executed on a local system without explicit installation or execution by the recipient."  (from wikipedia)

however i couldnt find anything useful related to mobile codes transferred on the network that explains them in details and that gives open source examples so i know what kind of programming i will be doing.

all im asking for is to give me resources  ( urls, books, .. ) just anything that i could read, understand and build upon.. because at this point, all i know about mobile codes are the definition i pasted above !! thank you :)))

PS: please let the resources u;ll be giving me be specific to the project i have to implement.

lookin forward for you replies :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I understand your boss, what he wants are "agents".  There are several libraries to make writing agents easier.

- IBM's [aglets](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-04-1997/jw-04-hood.html)
- [JADE (Java Agent DEvelopment Framework)](http://JADE)
- [JavaTM](http://www.wiley.com/legacy/compbooks/catalog/19135-3.htm)

Did you ever see *The Matrix*?  The description Morpheus gives Neo for "agents" describes software agents much more closely than it does government agents.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure JADE is active, but not very sure if Aglets are still maintained.